# Should Threads ever be static?

Tags: java, multithreading, static

I'm just starting to use multi-threading in my programs and I'm wondering if there's any drawbacks to declaring threads as static.

Comment: You mean storing a `Thread` instance in a static field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Broadly speaking you should avoid global/static variables where possible.  However, there is occasions where this is the simplest option.

There is nothing special to `Thread` which makes it a better or worse choice unless you consider the cleanup of ThreadLocal values esp when it comes to ClassLoading.

I would only make the Thread pool  `static` if you expect it to run for the life of the program but for a plain `Thread` you might consider not storing it in a field at all.